# Use p4 shelve in perl script without opening the editor

Tags: perl, perforce

I'm trying to shelve my changes via perl script. After running `p4 shelve` it opens up an editor where I need to enter the description, save and exit.

The problem I'm facing here is this script will be running on server side where we don't need user input so I need to handle this interactive mode to non-interactive so that I can shelve and proceed my next steps with shelved changelist. Are there any options ?

```
use P4;    
my $client = $ENV{client};
my $p4 = P4->new();
$p4->Connect();
$p4->SetClient($client);
$p4->Run('shelve');
```

Comment: yes, I'm using CPAN module

Comment: This might be helpful. https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4perl/Content/P4Perl/perl.programming.html#Programming_with_P4Perl, https://metacpan.org/release/SMEE/P4/view/P4.pm

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-c` flag to shelve an existing pending changelist rather than opening an editor to create a new numbered pending changelist.  I haven't used P4Perl, but according to the doc you can create a new changelist by doing something like:

```
$change = $p4->FetchChange();
$change->{ 'Description' } = "Some description";
$p4->SaveChange($change)  # get a $changenum from the output of this
```

so you should be able to do that and then shelve that changelist by doing:

```
$p4->Run('shelve', '-c', $changenum);
```

Comment: Last command returns an empty list`[]` and also one thing to mention is that `$change->{'Change'}` returns `new`. Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to save the change.  Lemme update the answer with how I'd guess you might do that.

Comment: Okay, it's not clear from the doc how exactly you get the changelist number from calling `SaveChange`, but you *should* be able to since it's returned as part of the `p4 change -i` output.

Comment: `$p4->SaveChange($change)` actually creates a new changelist and returns this `[Changelist 963564 got created]`. And after running the shelve command, it throws a bunch of error stating that argument is wrong in `$p4->Run()`

Comment: Use a regex to capture the `963564` part of that output, and then pass that as the `$changenum` in the `p4 shelve` command.

Comment: If you're doing that and getting an error message, it would be useful to know what the error message is, but `p4 shelve -c CHANGENUM` is how you shelve from the command line so it seems like it should work here.

Comment: yep, the command is right! But the issue here is it returns an empty list as I think `$change = $p4->FetchChange();` this line is creating a new change where files are not associated. I think that might be causing the problem of returning an empty list even after shelving

Comment: `p4 change -o` (`FetchChange`) should be giving you a pending changelist spec with all the files that are currently open in the default changelist.  Do you have files open in the default changelist when you start?

Comment: yep, `p4 opened` shows me the files that are opened on my client. But while doing `p4 change -o` changelist spec isn't showing any files list

Comment: That means that the files are open in an existing pending changelist (double-check the `p4 opened` output, it'll tell you what changelist they're opened in).  Run `p4 shelve -c CHANGENUM`, where `CHANGENUM` is the existing pending changelist, to shelve the files.

Comment: yep, you are right!